# mySQL query performance with INNER JOINs

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have what may be a basic performance question.  I've done a lot of SQL queries, but not much in terms of complex inner joins and such.  So, here it is:

I have a database with 4 tables, countries, territories, employees, and transactions.

The transactions links up with the employees and countries.  The employees links up with the territories.  In order to produce a required report, I'm running a PHP script that processes a SQL query against a mySQL database.

```
SELECT trans.transactionDate, agent.code, agent.type, trans.transactionAmount, agent.territory       
FROM transactionTable as trans 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT agent1.code as code, agent1.type as type, territory.territory as territory FROM agentTable as agent1 
    INNER JOIN territoryTable as territory 
    ON agent1.zip=territory.zip
) AS agent
ON agent.code=trans.agent 
ORDER BY trans.agent
```

There are about 50,000 records in the agent table, and over 200,000 in the transaction table.  The other two are relatively tiny.  It's taking about 7 minutes to run this query.  And I haven't even inserted the fourth table yet, which needs to relate a field in the transactionTable (country) to a field in the countryTable (country) and return a field in the countryTable (region).

So, two questions:

1. Where would I logically put the connection between the transactionTable and the countryTable?
2. Can anyone suggest a way that this can be quickened up?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can post your table structure, that would help a lot.  The biggest problem with your query is the SELECT inside the join.  That will take forever.  You also need to make sure you have the tables indexed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be equivalent to this:

```
SELECT tx.transactionDate,
       a.code,
       a.type,
       tx.transactionAmount,
       t.territory
FROM transactionTable tx,
     agentTable a,
     territoryTable t
WHERE tx.agent = a.code
  AND a.zip = t.zip
ORDER BY tx.agent
```

or to this if you like to use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT tx.transactionDate,
       a.code,
       a.type,
       tx.transactionAmount,
       t.territory
FROM transactionTable tx
JOIN agentTable a     ON tx.agent = a.code
JOIN territoryTable t ON a.zip = t.zip
ORDER BY tx.agent
```

In order to work fast, you must have following indexes on your tables:

```
CREATE INDEX transactionTable_agent ON transactionTable(agent);
CREATE INDEX territoryTable_zip     ON territoryTable(zip);
CREATE INDEX agentTable_code        ON agentTable(code);
```

(basically any field that is part of `WHERE` or `JOIN` constraint should be indexed).

That said, your table structure looks suspicious in a sense that it is joined by apparently non-unique fields like zip code. You really want to join by more unique entities, like agent id, transaction id and so on - otherwise expect your queries to generate a lot of redundant data and be really slow.

One more note: `INNER JOIN` is equivalent to simply `JOIN`, there is no reason to type redundant clause.

Comment: I've used the structure in your first example and it's going on 30 minutes now.  So, there's something wrong there.  Also as far as joining on fields, the territory table has an unique identifier that is zip.  There is only one record for each Zip Code.

Comment: Like I said, this query is equivalent to yours. You need to rethink what are you doing. Posting table structure and relationships between them can help us help you

Comment: i have a similar problem.. i have a join an for now is working fine but when the app get 50.000 user it might get super slow.. @Michael Reiland did you found the solution to these topic?